# CustomBinding with reliableSession Vs basicHttpBinding , incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded error

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted by IIS 7 on windows server 2008.

I need to support different configuration of the WCF service.

I have problem when I try to do bulk insertion of DataTabale of 600 rows of 4 Integers.

One Configuration is **CustomBinding with reliableSession**

**Client:**

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="reliableSessionOverHttps" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00">
      <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" flowControlEnabled="true" maxTransferWindowSize="4096" maxPendingChannels="4" ordered="true" maxRetryCount="4" reliableMessagingVersion="Default" acknowledgementInterval="00:10:00"/>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" manualAddressing="false" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

**My server Config:**

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="reliableSessionOverHttps" receiveTimeout="00:01:00"
           sendTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:01:00"
           closeTimeout="00:05:00">
      <reliableSession />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Everything works fine.

But when I use **basicHttpBinding** I get: "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element".

**Client:**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindNoCert" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00"  
       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"  transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

**Server:**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding" receiveTimeout="00:01:00"
           sendTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:01:00"
           closeTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

I get the error on this configuration.

Any idea why ? and how to resolve it ? (I know I can send it in smaller bulks)

Answer (score 0):

You also have to increase the maxBufferSize server side. It has to be the same as you maxReceivedMessageSize. You should also decrease your size to a more reasonable size. 2GB is far to large and will only use resources or make you vulnerable to attacks. Use 2MB: 2097152.

Comment: thanks but you didn't answer my question, why on custom binding it works while on basicHttp its fails.It's the same server config.